Xenomai installation in the system which have nvidia GPU(GeForce 940MX)
Can we install Xenomai 3 on ubuntu 20.04 in the system which have Nvidia GeForce 940MX GPU? If its possible means how to install it?
Is the Xenomai 3 compatible with Nvidia GeForce 940MX?
